# How to make content has fixed margin to the bottom of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a HTML page with various height content. Sometimes when the content is not that much, the content will be next to the bottom of the browser window and that is quite ugly.

Is there anyway to add a margin or padding to the bottom?

For example, I want to add some margin between "Some Div" and the bottom browser chrome.

[image: Here is a screen shot]

Comment: Tried, What have you?

Comment: use `margin-bottom:50px;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.some-div {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

or

```
.some-div {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo It's best to create a http://jsfiddle.net that shows the problem you're having. So then we can solve the problem. Also please include the relevant code in your question.